# MySQL : How to identify users I follow or follow me from other person's followers?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create a twitter like follow/following system. The table design is like this -

```
leader_id | following_id | is_mutual
        1 |            2 | 1 // Mutually follow each other
        2 |            1 | 1
        1 |            3 | 0 
        1 |            4 | 1
        4 |            1 | 1
```

Let's say I'm `user_id=4`. I'm viewing the followers of `user_id=1`. I'll see the list -

```
2
3
4 -> me
```

How can I determine which of these users I'm following or follow me. I'm looking to write a Laravel Eloquent statement for this. Even MySQL query would help me figure out the right way to do this.

Comment: Inconsistent data? I expected to see (1 | 4 | 1).

Comment: Updated. It should be 1 | 4 | 1 .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Because basic sql can do this job. like select following_id as follower from follower where leader_id = 1;

Comment: I've setup belongsToMany relationship. However, when I'm viewing other person's followers, I'm unable to figure out the right way to find the users that I'm following or follow me. Super stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go that way.

Rather have a one-to-many relationship table of subscriptions like

```
|subscriber  | subscribed_user_id 
---------------------------------
|1           | 2
|1           | 3
|2           | 3
|3           | 1
```

or even json encoded flexible list

```
|subscriber  | subscribed_users
-------------------------------
|1           | {2,3}
|2           | {3}
|3           | {1}
```

Comment: Yes, I've a one-to-many relationship. However, the real trouble is finding my followers / users I follow in other persons's followers. I can't figure out any way to write query or a statement without first fetching the entire list of other person's followers into memory and then checking them one by one. The system fails when the followers list is too big (say 1 million)

Comment: Its just a reversed lookup - `SELECT subscriber FROM subscription_table WHERE subscribed_user_id = :my_user_id`